# Bluetooth headphones noise irritating beep sound

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, ear-phones

I have a Bose QC35 model 1 which I quite like and use with two iPhones, an iPad, two MacBooks, Apple TV. Also have home pod around.

Problem is that it seems to keep probing different devices all the time, perhaps to auto connect to the correct one. But while doing this is emits a noise irritating beep sound. This is getting to a point where I have to stop using the headphone.

I tried to use AirPods Pro for a while and looks like there is no such a thing with them.

I'm wondering what's going on? Is this a problem with Bose headphones? Any non Apple headphones present this issue? What about AirPods max?

Comment: Mine just connects to two devices and is then happy.

Comment: You mean on the Bose iPhone app you only have two devices at all? Q35 model 1 or 2?

Comment: I have several devices, when I switch the headphones on it connects to two devices.  QC35 II